# Using JWT in laravel 5.1 api

Tags: php, facebook, jwt

I'm trying to implement a nice `JWT` based api, so I have already read loads of documentation about `JWTs` and how they work, but I can't figure out a few things:

1. When the user logs in to the app, do I pass user details via `JWT`? For example, the `name,`email and user `permissions`.
2. Do I need to pass everything via `JWT`? For example, getting the page specific data from the database or getting all blog posts or something similar to that.
3. How do I find out on back-end whether the user has a permission to do this action or not? How can I get the user details from the token?
4. I'm using `Tymon/JWT-Auth` library in this case and here is a little demonstration of how my application works at the moment:

   1. User sends  a `post` request to `api/authenticate` route, which logs the user in and returns a `JWT` token as `json` along with the user details - `name`, `email` and `permissions`. So the data returned from the server looks like this:

   `{
       "token": "blablabla",
       "user": {
           "email": "testin@test.com",
           "name": "Test User",
           "permissions": [ "can_edit_posts", "can_delete_users" ]
       }
   }`

   `JWT` is stored in a global variable in javascript called `token`. The user data is stored in a user object.

   2. User goes to the let's say `blogs` page. This page sends a `GET` request to the server, that retrieves all the posts: `/blogs?token=[THAT_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_HERE]`
   3. The server returns the list of all the posts.
   4. The global token variable is updated with whatever is in the `Bearer` key in the header.

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

you must append your token to a special http header called Authorization, for example with this pattern :

```
headers('Authorization: JWT aer5a4era456f4asrgt1aer46a');
```